# Perform resumable uploads using google-cloud-node

Tags: javascript, express, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-node

This code works great for normal uploads, but I am wondering how the resumable upload works when, for example, the user loses connection in the middle of a large upload. Is setting resumable to true in the writeStream options the only thing necessary for this to work?

Ive read through this link on [performing resumable uploads](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/resumable-upload), but it seems, that the [createWriteStream](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/storage/1.1.0/storage/file?method=createWriteStream) function should encapsulate this behavior.

I have tried testing this out by turning off my wifi in the middle of an upload, but the time it takes to finish uploading once I resume upload is the same as an uninterrupted upload which is why i'm not sure if this is actually working.

Any help or explanation is appreciated, let me know if I can clarify anything.

```js
stream = remoteFile.createWriteStream({gzip: true, resumable: true, metadata: {contentType: file.mimetype} });

stream.on('error', (err: any) => {
    next(err);
    res.status(400).send('err');
});

stream.on('finish', () => {
    res.status(200).send('Success!');
});

stream.end(file.buffer);
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't trust the resumable metadata option as the only way to make the upload resumable so I followed the instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/resumable-upload). I have attached my code below. This is for a single request resumable upload, NOT multiple chunk.

#### First I send a POST request to the bucket upload url to receive the resumable session uri

```js
let url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/bucketname/o?uploadType=resumable&name=testing';

let objBody = JSON.stringify({'metadata': {'someDataPoint': req.body.someDataPoint}});

let contentLength: number = Buffer.byteLength(objBody, 'utf-8');

let options = {
  url: url,
  method: 'POST',
  body: objBody,
  headers: {
    'Content-Length': contentLength,
    'X-Upload-Content-Type': req.file.mimetype,
    'X-Upload-Content-Length': req.file.size,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
  }
};

request(options, (error: any, response: any, body: any, stat: any) => {

    if (response && response.statusCode === 200) {
        // send response.headers.location to next function for put request

    } else {
        console.log('err!', error);
        res.status(400).send(error);
    }

});
```

#### Then I send a PUT request to the received session uri with my file data

```js
let url = resumableUri;

let options = {
    url: url,
    method: 'PUT',
    body: req.file.buffer,
    headers: {
        'Content-Length': req.file.size,
        'Content-Type': req.file.mimetype,
    }
};

request(options, (error: any, response: any, body: any, stat: any) => {

  if (response && response.statusCode === 200) {
      res.status(200).send('ok');
  } else if (response && response.statusCode >= 500) {
      // send request to resume upload
  } else {
      // try upload again
  }

});
```

Comment: I am interested in your answer. Can you help me understand it, what is the content of "someDataPoint" is it the payload of the body?